# Edit button below question is greyed out

Tags: support, bug

I was trying to edit a question (to change some formatting), but the edit link was greyed out.

The question I'm talking about : [I need to find the Ka of a weak acid in titration with a strong base](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/28545/i-need-to-find-the-ka-of-a-weak-acid-in-titration-with-a-strong-base)

[image: Question snippet]

Is this a bug or is there some reason behind me not able to edit the question?

Comment: Yup. Santiago pretty much sums up everything! On half-mods (people more than 2k on betas and 10k on graduated sites) you see the edit button with a `(1)` beside it. Until we choose to improve the edit or approve or reject it, NO ONE will be able to edit.

Comment: Even when you are above the threshold and already voted to approve/reject, it is not possible to edit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That means that an edit has already been submitted for that question. If you hover over the grayed out edit button, the tool tip tells you that there is another edit in the works and that you can't edit while it is in the queue.